# Refer directly to one precise cell in SAS

Tags: macros, sas, cell

I have, for reproductibility reasons, all the parameters needed for one of my programs stocked into an Excel file.
I can then do a *proc import* to have this Excel seen as a Sas database, which works.

But then I wonder if there is a simple way to access some particular values in this "database". I would like to be able to write code like

```
if var1 < "line 5, column F4" then var2= 3*"line 5, colmun F5"
```

and so on. One problem is that there is a lot of parameters of different nature, so that the sas database created is not a clean one.

It is a relatively short dataset (around 15 rows and 10 columns), so even if it is not the best programming thing to do, I was thinking maybe a way would be to run  a program on the whole dataset that creates a macro variable A1, A2 and so on, but I am not sure on how to do that.

Thanks

**EDIT1 : what the excel looks like**

[image]

**EDIT2**
 More generally, my problem is that I have the following program that has to be run annually, but the numerical values change over time, and there has been years in which people charged to change them did not change all of them, so that we are trying a way to make the change of these value more automatic

```
 /* LORSQUE DANS UN FOYER IL Y A DES ENFANTS LES PARTS SONT ATTRIBUEES A LA PERSONNE     AYANT LES REVENUS LES PLUS ELEVES */
N=1;
if first.nomen then N=N+(nbenf=1)*.5+(nbenf=2)+(nbenf>2)*(nbenf-1);

/* On calcule les abattements de pensions-retraites sur zperi  (il faudrait ventiler en zreti, zalri, zrtoi pour affiner car le régime d'abattement n'est pas le meme pour les pensions et les rentes) l'impot est calculé individuellement */

if activite='3333' /*au chômage toute l'année page 313(Brochure pratique: fiche de calculs)*/
then ab10s=int(min(max(min(0.1*ztsai,12000),924),ztsai));
else ab10s=int(min(max(min(0.1*ztsai,12000),421),ztsai));
           /*Pensions retraites P285(fiche de calculs)*/
ab10r=int(min(max(min(0.1*zperi,3660),374),zperi));;

/* Calcul du montant du revenu net imposable */
mrni=int(sum(ztsai,-ab10s,zperi,-ab10r,zragi,zrici,zrnci));
/* Abattement spécial pour les plus de 65 ans */
if aneec<"&nais65" then
do;
    if mrni<14510 then mrni=max(0,sum(mrni,-2312));else   /*page 308*/
    if mrni<23390 then mrni=sum(mrni,-1156);
end;

    /* Calcul du Quotient Familial */
    QF=mrni/N;
    /* Maj le 17/06/2014 - 1 tranche haute supplémentaire en 2012*/
ir=int(max(0,
( 5963 < QF <= 11896) * (mrni*0.055 -  327.97*N)
+(11896 < QF <= 26420) * (mrni*0.14  - 1339.13*N)
+(26420 < QF <= 70830) * (mrni*0.30  - 5566.33*N)
+(70830 < QF <= 150000) * (mrni*0.41  -13357.63*N)
+(150000< QF        ) * (mrni*0.45  -19357.63*N)));

/* PLAFONNEMENT DU QUOTIENT FAMILIAL */
/*     P 289 plafonnement du quotient familial*/
ir2=int(max(0,
( 5963 < QF <= 11896) * (mrni*0.055 -  327.97*N)
+(11896 < QF <= 26420) * (mrni*0.14  - 1339.13*N)
+(26420 < QF <= 70830) * (mrni*0.30  - 5566.33*N)
+(70830 < QF <= 150000) * (mrni*0.41  -13357.63*N)
+(150000< QF        ) * (mrni*0.45  -19357.63*N)));

ir2=max(0,ir2-2000*(N-1)/.5); /*page 317*/

if ir<ir2 then ir=ir2;

/* DECOTE */ /*page 317*/

if ir<960 then ir=max(0,ir-(480-(ir/2)));

/* SEUIL DE MISE EN RECOUVREMENT */

if ir<61 then ir=0;  
run;
```

Comment: Are the values all numeric, or a combination of numeric and character?

Comment: All the parameters I ultimately need are numerical. However there is text in the excel file (to explain what each parameter is).

Comment: Could you publish a sample of what the imported dataset looks like?

Comment: I just put my table for one year.

Comment: Are the cells/location of the parameters constant from year to year? I would read in each set of parameters individually using DDE. Painful the first time but works well after that.

Comment: Mostly yes. It is a program that simulates the income tax. It can happen that there are major legal changes sometimes but most years, it is just a change in brackets or rates.

Answer (score 1):

this task is usually not handled with sas.
Anyway a method you can use is defining a macro that will put in a macro variable each of the comparison term.

```
%macro comp(line=,var=,temp=);
data _null_;
set have;
if _N_=&line then call symputx("&temp","&var",'g');
run;
%mend;
```

and then call it before a datastep for example in your case:

```
if var1 < "line 5, column F4" then var2= 3*"line 5, colmun F5"
```

you will do:

```
%comp(line=5,var=F4,temp=first);
%comp(line=5,var=F5,temp=second);

data want;
set have;
if var1 < &first. then var2 = 3*&second.;
run;
```

let me know if you need further support.

Comment: Then how is this task usually handled ? I edited my question to explain where it comes from but I am not sure it is the best way to handle the global problem

Comment: It is usually handled in Excel.  SAS is more like a database; while it's _technically possible_ to do it this way in SAS, you wouldn't usually actually do so.  You're combining data with output formatting, which something like Word or Excel does, but SAS really prefers to keep data in a database-type structure and then report out from that.

Comment: thanks @Joe, your answers are always great here. 
Antony also please look at Haikuo Bian's answer, it could be a very good and fast solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using direct access "point= + variable" name approach, if you have a large table and you don't need any other information beside the 'coordinates' you are after.